Converting shapefiles to GeoJSON with specific structure in QGIS
I work in agriculture and at the moment I'm the only GIS techy in our organisation. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of programming experience.
For a certain applicator we have to convert shapefiles provided by one company to the GeoJSON format used by that applicator. The part I'm struggling to automate is that you have to assign IDs to certain zones. Here is how I have been doing it manually:


Select a field in the "o_name" column and then select by location all other features that intersect the field.

In the "o_id column assign the same integer value for all fields, this is sequential for all fields starting with 1

In the "z_id" column assign numbering with @row_number except for the field in o_name that has a value, those were all assigned 0.


It's simple enough, but once you have to do it over 300 times it gets time-consuming. Is there maybe a way of automating it using the model designer?

You start by selecting the first row in o_name column, then select all other rows intersecting that one selected polygon?

Welcome to the community! Please provide more details so that we can help you.

Your question seems solvable, but you probably need to provide some more details about the file format (and/or attach some sample data).

The initial format is a shapefile that I edit the column headings to like like those above:
o_id: orchard index (sequential, integer, starting at 1)
o_name: orchard name (descriptive text name for the orchard)
z_id: zone id (sequential, integer, starting at 0, restarts for each orchard)
df: deposition faction (decimal >= 0)
and then export the file as GeoJSON.
Not sure if that helps.

Within the one file, can you have different names in the o_name column? What determines whether there is a value or a NULL in that column? Is the o_id field populated when you get the file or does it need to be populated? Basically, assume that the audience for the question knows nothing about the file formats. It is often worthwhile attaching sample data (more than a 5 line screenshot). Also, remember to edit any info in the comments back into the question.
